# SQL If Else in inside query string

Tags: sql, sql-server

Can something like this can be done?

```
"SELECT * FROM account WHERE if(@dropdownsearch) = 'ID' then id=@id else name=@name"
```

because I can't if else outside the query string maybe because of this:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddRange(queryParams.ToArray());
```

please help

Answer (score 4):

use `AND/OR` logic

```
SELECT * 
FROM account 
WHERE (@dropdownsearch = 'ID' and id=@id) 
   or name=@name
```

Comment: I think the second condition should be `(@dropdownsearch != 'ID' and name=@name)`

Comment: No, your query will return the redundant rows (`name = @name`) when `@dropdownsearch = 'ID'`

Comment: @TriV As per my assumption `@id` and `@name` will never have values at same time

Comment: @Pரதீப் yea, they will never have values at the same time

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your dilemma correctly, you have a dropdown where a user may select whether to search on ID or Name. Now you need to pass one or the other in, not both, correct?
I have done this before, with multiple dropdown options, using the following logic:

```
SELECT * FROM account 
WHERE
  (CASE WHEN @dropdownsearch = 'ID' then @id else ID END) = ID,
  (CASE WHEN @dropdownsearch = 'Name' then @name else name END) = name
```

So what happens here is if they have selected ID then it will compare the value in your @id parameter to that of ID. At the same breath it will compare name to itself. (Name)Hanzou = (Name)Hanzou is always true, so every value in name will pass and @name will be ignored.
The reverse works if the user selected 'Name' instead of 'ID'